# Find the area inside the lemniscate $r^2 = 8 cos 2\theta$ and outside the circle $r = 2$.

Tags: calculus, integration, trigonometry, polar-coordinates, area

[Function Plotter graph](https://functionplotter.com/#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-):

---

[image]

---

I think the formula is

$$A = \frac 1 2 \int_{\alpha}^{\beta} (\text{outer})^2 - (\text{inner})^2 d\theta$$

where $\alpha, \beta$ are [where they intersect](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=4+%3D+8cos(2x),+0+%3C%3D+x+%3C%3D+2pi) in $[0, 2\pi]$.

This is what I got based on that

By symmetry, we have

$$\frac A 4 = \frac 1 2 \int_{0}^{\pi/6} (8 cos 2\theta) - (2)^2 d\theta$$

Is that right?

Comment: Looks right to me.

Comment: @MatthewLeingang Is that really the formula? I don't think my book has given an exact formula involving 'outer' and 'inner'

Comment: If you think about subtracting the areas of the polar regions from the origin to the outer and inner curves, this is what it would have to be.

Comment: @MatthewLeingang thanks ^-^

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Which one is in your book? $$\frac A4=\int_0^{\frac{\pi}6}\int_2^{\sqrt{8\cos(2\theta)}}rdrd\theta=\int_0^{\frac{\pi}6}\frac12(8\cos(2\theta)-2^2)d\theta=2\sin(\frac{\pi}3)-\frac{\pi}3=0.68$$

Comment: Oh the single integral formula is based on the double integral formula. Never thought of it that way. Thanks user115350 ^-^